# bash: Automatically install package if not installed

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, package, apt-get

Let's say I thought I had SVN installed. I run the command and I get the following output:

```
aoneill@aoneill-Laptop:~/Documents$ svn
The program 'svn' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

My question is: Can I change the output, or catch such a situation, to say something like the following, with a prompt at the end?

```
aoneill@aoneill-Laptop:~/Documents$ svn
The program 'svn' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install subversion

Install the package? [y/n]
```

Thank you! It would make package handling that much nicer!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/309178/ask-to-install-program-after-the-program-x-is-currently-not-installed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Exactly what you are looking for](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309178/ask-to-install-program-after-the-program-x-is-currently-not-installed):

```
export COMMAND_NOT_FOUND_INSTALL_PROMPT=1
```